# Using array and mirror for modeling

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Hi Blenderstack commun:)
Trying to create a certain pattern using Array modifier Mirror modifier and 
like maybe a shrink wrap? I think?...
I'm trying to recreate the handle wrap without having to like sculpt it by hand:)

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be more simple to find a material of it? I don't think this pattern is that unique to find a similar one.

Comment: I already looked all over the internet for one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to find the pattern, use a plane, rotate it 45°, squeeze it to make a lozenge, duplicate and mirror it on the X axis.

[image]

Then subdivide, extrude and begin to move the edges so that the array copies will fit. Give it a first *Array* modifier on the X axis, then a second *Array* on the Z axis. To make it turn around give it a *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode. Also give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. You can still modify the original mesh to give any correction. If the pattern is not supposed to rotate around a cylinder but around another shape, just give your object a *Curve* modifier with the good curve shape instead of a *Simple Deform*.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! this is it!